# How to set watermark resolution according to video resolution?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Here i am trying to create a video editor with top and bottom text.I can set 2 text on top and bottom with different size, color and fonts for that text and i am converting that text to image and adding as watermark.

But when resolution of video decreases the size of watermark image increase and vise versa.I am using ffmpeg commands.Now i am calculating like as shown below.

```
  if (video_width <= 300) {

                Log.e("less than", "300");
                water_resolution_bt = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_width / 2 + 30) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_height / 2 + 15));

                water_resolution = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_width / 2 + 30) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_height / 2 + 15));

            } else if (video_width > 300 && video_width <= 400) {

                Log.e("less than", "400");
                water_resolution_bt = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_width / 2 + 130) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_height / 2 + 70));

                water_resolution = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_width / 2 + 130) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_height / 2 + 70));

            } else if (video_width > 400 && video_width <= 600) {
                Log.e("btw ", "400 and 600");
                water_resolution_bt = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_width + 80) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_height + 40));

                water_resolution = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_width + 80) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_height + 40));
            } else if (video_width > 600 && video_width <= 1000) {
                Log.e("btw ", "600 and 1000");
                water_resolution_bt = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_width + 100) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_height + 100));

                water_resolution = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_width + 100) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_height + 100));

            } else if (video_width > 1000) {
                Log.e("grthr than ", "1000");
                water_resolution = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_width * 2 + 20) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_top_height * 2 + 20));
                water_resolution_bt = String.valueOf(getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_width * 2 + 20) + ":" + getDPsFromPixels(getApplicationContext(), tv_bt_height * 2 + 20));

            }
```

This will not give accurate results.Can anyone suggest any other calculation methods.I have also tried with "drawtext" method .It also have same issue.

Comment: Use drawtext and set `fontsize=H/10` This will set fontsize to 10% of video height.

Comment: i don't want a fixed height.It may change with the text size give to the text.